# $A_n$ converges to zero and $B_n$ is bounded but not necessarily convergent, then $A_nB_n$ converges to $0$

Tags: analysis

I'm having trouble with this:
Prove that if $A_n$ converges to zero and $B_n$ is bounded but not necessarily convergent, then $A_nB_n$ converges to $0$.

I'm not sure about what I have up to now (it's a summary):
Using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, we can find a convergent subsequence to $B_n$ (let's call it $B_{n_{k}}$) such that $A_nB_{n_{k}}$ converges to $0$ (by algebra on convergent sequences)

What about all the elements of $B_n$ that are not in $B_{n_{k}}$?

By the way, I know there is a proof with the squeeze theorem, but is there another method?

Sorry for all the spelling mistakes and the fact that I don't know formatting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $(b_n)_b$ bounded in absolute value by an $M$. Let $\varepsilon\in\mathbf{R}_{+}^{\times}$. As $(a_n)_n$ converges to $0$, there exists an $N$ such that for $n\geq N$ we have $|a_n|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{M}$. Then, if $n\geq N$, you have $|a_n b_n| = |a_n||b_n| \leq M\times \frac{\varepsilon}{M} = \varepsilon$ which shows, by the quatification, that $(a_n b_n)_n$ converges to $0$.

Comment: You are welcome. There are plenty of exercises of this kind that you should train with to work out the $\varepsilon / N$ stuff.